# What is IN.worldRefl in surface shader Input struct?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg, shaderlab

The question is pretty straight-forward. I have no idea what `IN.worldRefl` stands for, I've seen some tutorials using it with cubemaps but I still have no clue.

Unity's [description](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html) for it is very poor:

> float3 worldRefl - contains world reflection vector *if surface shader*
>   *does not write to o.Normal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been researching for a few days now and I have a hunch about what `IN.worldRefl` means.

First I saw this image (found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Reflecting_Surfaces)):

[image]

So I guess that `IN.worldRefl` is the reflection of the camera ray in the surface of a polygon of an object, as shown in the image.

When one set, for example, the emission of the `SurfaceOutput` to be the texture of a cubemap in the position corresponding to `IN.worldRefl`, that is

```
samplerCUBE _Cube;
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb;
}
```

it means that, setting the object inside a cube with the given cubemap, the reflected ray of the camera in the object polygon' surface will cross the cube in a point. The color of this point will be emitted by the object in the position where the camera ray touches the object.

I can be totally wrong but this makes sense to me.